# How to configure java memory heap space for hadoop mapreduce?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, heap-memory, shuffle

I've tried to run a mapreduce job on about 20 GB data, and I got an error on reduce shuffle phase. It says that because of memory heap space. Then, I've read on many source, that I have to decrease the mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.input.buffer.percent property on mapred-site.xml with the default value 0,7. So, I decrease it to 0,2.

I want to ask, is that property take an effect on time performance my mapreduce job. So, how can I properly configure to make my mapreduce job never get an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.input.buffer.percent   0.70    The percentage of memory to be allocated from the maximum heap size to storing map outputs during the shuffle. 
From this it looks that that if you decrease this to a arbitrary value it may degrade the performance of the shuffle phase.
There would have been certain reasoning and tests behind the default value 
You may check other related properties here 
http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml

What is the approx data output by your mappers ,If that is huge then you may want to increase the number of mappers
Likewise if the number of reducers is low heap space error could likely happen during reduce phase.

you may want to check your job counters and increase the number of mappers/reducers
you may also try increasing the mapper/reducer memory
by setting the properties *mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb* and *mapreduce.map.memory.mb*

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, I want to ask again, so the hadoop mapreduce can get the task failed when we wrong on memory configuration. So, we can say that, this issue depends on the number of records, so, how hadoop deal with this issue or minimize the failure risk?

Thanks2

Comment: Ideally shuffle should not have this issue.That is what big data is,things are not expected to fit in memory there was a bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-1182 .Are you on a old version? If a reduce task goes out of memory then it is a programmers mistake (num of reducers too low or bad custom partitioning)

Comment: by the way I use hadoop 2.6.0, I set the number of reduce task the same as the number of slave nodes, what do you think?

Comment: I am able to get a similar issue now and this is a open bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-6108 .Finding a suitable value for your data set and memory system can be a workaround

Comment: okok thanks a lot, by the way can I ask something else. In hadoop yarn how can we get the total memory and cpu usage from the application. We can get it per job, or per application, on total usage or we can get per node usage? Thanks....

Comment: the yarn resource manager UI has these details of the cluster and nodes.Even the job counters have these details for the job